# ember-pouch: acceptance test strategies

Tags: ember.js, pouchdb

I am using ember-pouch as my adapter for an ember-cli app (v3.0.0).

For acceptance tests, I'd like to use the pouchDb adapter rather than mock everything. To implement this it seems the best strategy would be to:

1) create a new pouch-db instance at the start of each test and

2) destroy this instance at the end of each test

It seems like the best way to do it would be to use the beforeEach and afterEach hooks in the test.  But I've been searching for two days and cannot find any useful documentation on how to implement this strategy.

Can somebody help me out with some pointers on how to implement this strategy on test setup?

Comment: Having coupled (front-end) acceptance tests to a specific adapter before, I don't recommend it because then when a test fails it isn't clear if it's because of a problem with the front-end of back-end plus it dramatically increases the amount of work required to change the adapter later. Since it's so popular and flexible, I've started using [`ember-cli-mirage`](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage) ([docs](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.4.x/)) for the acceptance tests regardless of the actual adapter used in the application.